# plotting a route on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How would I use Google Maps API to plot a route? E.g to have a bunch of way points loaded onto the map (I currently have this) and draw a line from each of them showing the user a route they could take to see all of them? How would I then load this up when the user see's the map?

Comment: If I can add to my answer to clarify, please let me know.

Comment: @Cannonade Yeah, that'd be nice.. sorry.. could I get an example? just a little confused

Comment: I will implement an example and update my answer as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more sample code and a link to a working example.  Hope this helps.

Comment: can anyone help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495330/having-issue-with-plotting-the-routes-on-the-google-map ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set the *waypoints* property on a [DirectionsService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService) object and it will plot the route from the source to the destination via all the points in your array:

> Array of intermediate waypoints.
>   Directions will be calculated from the
>   origin to the destination by way of
>   each waypoint in this array.

Once you have set the *waypoints* property, you call the route method to calculate the directions:

```
route(request:DirectionsRequest, callback:function(DirectionsResult, DirectionsStatus)))
```

Once you have your DirectionsResult, you can use the [DirectionsRenderer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRenderer) object to render the results on a Google Map.

**Update with working example**

The following code makes a direction request between hardcoded start and end points via an array of three waypoints:

```
// three points through which the directions pass
var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8975098545041,151.09962701797485);
var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8584421519279,151.0693073272705);
var point3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.84525521656404,151.0421848297119);

// build an array of the points
var wps = [{ location: point1 }, { location: point2 }, {location: point3}];

// set the origin and destination
var org = new google.maps.LatLng ( -33.89192157947345,151.13604068756104);
var dest = new google.maps.LatLng ( -33.69727974097957,150.29047966003418);

var request = {
        origin: org,
        destination: dest,
        waypoints: wps,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
```

You can find a working example of this code [here](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo31) ([source](http://www.cannonade.net/geo31.js)).

**N.B.** Keep in mind you can only use up to eight waypoints in your array, unless you switch to a business account.

Comment: A B C is showing as markers on the map. Where are they set? How do I change this to be blank or to the title on the place?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static map, then loop through your points and plot the points using the path param.

Something like:

```
&path=color:blue|weight:5|45.123,-123.595|46.456,-124.985
```

Comment: Could please share the complete code for which you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this on Android.
Google has a service for this here is the link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro

You'll find an example API call on this page here. Plus some web instructions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

This is an example web call to the service.
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=-35.27801,149.12958|-35.28032,149.12907|-35.28099,149.12929|-35.28144,149.12984|-35.28194,149.13003|-35.28282,149.12956|-35.28302,149.12881|-35.28473,149.12836&interpolate=true&key=YOUR_API_KEY

If memory serves, I believe you can have up to 100 points per call and you get charged by each call regardless of the amount of points.

This above call can also be configured to snap to roads.

As far as drawing the routs when the map loads, this depends on what technologies you are using. I know that it's easy to in .NET WinForms

If you post a comment on your question; letting me know what technologies you are using I may be able to give you some further advice.

If you want to test your routes for free, I found a nifty little web site:
https://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/

Hope this helps.