# Plotting bus route with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working on a property rental site. On the site I'd like to have a Google map, with all of the properties marked, and the local bus routes drawn, so that renters can see the proximity of the properties to the route.

I've achieved the first part of the problem; I've plotted the properties using markers. Now I need to add the bus route.

I've looked in to this and I can't quite work out the best way to achieve it. I looked at polylines and at using [this tool](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html), but the route is complex and would take hundreds of co-ordinates.

There is some kind of route api, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404499/plotting-a-route-on-google-maps) but apparently it can only take 8 waypoints. Is that right?

Ideally I'd like to draw the map by selecting a start point, an end point, and dragging the route into place; and then somehow importing that route into what I have.

Here is the exact route that I want to import: http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/services/accommodation/landlords/12busroutes/.

My code to plot the properties is:

```
var siteRoot = "<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/";

var markers = [
  <?php 
  $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=properties' );
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      kdev_maps('list');
    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
    ?>
]; 

function googlemap() {

jQuery('#map_canvas').css({'height': '400px'});

// Create the map 
// No need to specify zoom and center as we fit the map further down.
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  streetViewControl: false
});

// Create the shared infowindow with two DIV placeholders
// One for a text string, the other for the StreetView panorama.
var content = document.createElement("div");
var title = document.createElement("div");
var boxText = document.createElement("div");

var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-117,-200)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
          background: "url('"+siteRoot+"images/house-icon-flat.png') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 1
          ,width: "240px"
          ,height: "190px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 0px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://kdev.langley.com/wp-content/themes/langley/images/close.png"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
};


var infoWindow = new InfoBox(myOptions);
var MarkerImage = siteRoot+'images/house-web-marker.png';

// Create the markers
for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
function addMarker(data) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        content: data.html,
        icon: MarkerImage
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, this);         
        title.innerHTML = marker.getTitle();
        infoWindow.setContent(marker.content);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        jQuery(".innerinfo").parent().css({'overflow':'hidden', 'margin-right':'10px'});            
    });
}

// Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
// This logic could be conbined with the marker creation.
// Just keeping it separate for code clarity.
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (index in markers) {
    var data = markers[index];
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
var origcent = new google.maps.LatLng(map.getCenter());
// Handle the DOM ready event to create the StreetView panorama
// as it can only be created once the DIV inside the infowindow is loaded in the DOM.

closeInfoWindow = function() {
    infoWindow.close();
};

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', closeInfoWindow);

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function()
{
    centermap();
});

function centermap()
{
    map.setCenter(map.fitBounds(bounds));
}

}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
googlemap();
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth looking at two things:

1) The GTFS format (https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference) this is a csv-based format that allows someone to cross reference transit times and routes, if you are lucky then the data will have been assembled for you for your transit authority :)

2) If you can pull in the coordinates then you can make a line feature as long as you want (within the bounds of browser capacity). This is done in much the same way as you pull in markers, except you pull the features you want into a polyline:
like this (from gmaps docs):

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

you will build your array from php, of course :)

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use free google maps you can use a start point, end point and 8 way point. In google maps api premiere you can use 23 way point for routing vehicles