# Compute path between 2 points with Google Map Direction Service

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I'm trying to draw a path between points on a map. I have an array of 2 points (for my tests).
I can draw them on the map easily but it looks like the Direction Service is not working as expected.

This is what I should get according google map:
[image]

But this is what I get:
[image]

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxwell2022/wY32u/3/).

And here is my testing code:

```
var map = undefined;

function initialize() 
{
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.885026, 151.268316),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 14
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    initialize();
    loadPaths(map);
});

function loadPaths(gmap)
{
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        pathPoints = [], 
        index=0,
        positions = [
        {latitude: "-33.88914",longitude: "151.25673"},
        {latitude: "-33.888",longitude: "151.2623"},
    ];

    // The fix
    positions.reverse();

    $.each(positions, function(k, v) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(v.latitude, v.longitude);
        pathPoints.push(myLatlng);
        index++;
    });

    // Intialize the Path Array
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

    // Intialise the Direction Service
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var iconSymbol = {
        path: 'M 40 20 L 80 20 L 100 40 L 100 140 L 20 140 L 20 40 Z',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(60, 10),
        scale: 0.15,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: 'steelblue',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
    };

    // Set the Path Stroke Color
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: gmap,
        strokeColor: '#dd0000',
        icons: [{
            icon: iconSymbol
        }]
    });

    // Draw the path for this vehicle
    // We compute the path between each point to follow the road
    for (var i = 0; i < pathPoints.length; i++) {
        // If it's not the last point
        if ((i + 1) < pathPoints.length) {
            var src = pathPoints[i];
            var des = pathPoints[i + 1];

            // We had the starting point to the poly path
            path.push(src);

            // We compute the path between the 2 points
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    // We add the new computed points
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Set the path of the polyline to draw it
    poly.setPath(path);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the issue of the path thanks to @anto
But I still have an issue time to time, the path is not drew on the road. I think it's an `asynchronous` issue with the service callback function but I'm not sure how I can fix it.
If I relaunch the script in jsfiddle it's working randomly, but sometime I end up with this kind of drawing:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like using a recursive function is fixing most of it, except that my last point is not drawn: http://jsfiddle.net/maxwell2022/wY32u/11/

Comment: Are you sure that is two-way street? Travel mode WALKING returns shorter path.

Comment: If you exchange lat/lng values in start/stop you will get the same path at Google Map site.

Comment: Correct, I have to update my question because I still have an issue with 3 points.

Comment: I feel like I need a recursive function to get the full path before to draw it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behaviour google maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176212/inconsistent-behaviour-google-maps-v3)

Comment: @geocodezip Please see comments to your answer on the other SOF question. cheers

Answer (score 1):

**As click on google map first time its create start point  as click second time on map it creates end point in map and displays route on map**

[image]

```
>       var map;
    >         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    >         var wayA;
    >         var wayB;
    >         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    >         var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    >             suppressMarkers: true,
    >             panel: document.getElementById('right-panel'),
    >             draggable: true
    >         });
    >         var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    >         var data = {};
    >         initMap();
    >         function initMap() {
    >             debugger;
    >             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('rmap'), {
    >                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.030357, 72.517845),
    >                 zoom: 15
    >             });
    >             google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
    >                 if (!wayA) {
    >                     wayA = new google.maps.Marker({
    >                         position: event.latLng,
    >                         map: map,
    >                         icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|00FF00|000000"
    >                     });
    >                 } else {
    >                     if (!wayB) {
    >                         debugger;
    >                         wayB = new google.maps.Marker({
    >                             position: event.latLng,
    >                             map: map,
    >                             icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=E|FF0000|000000"
    >                         });
    >                         calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, wayA, wayB);
    >                     }
    >                 }
    >             });
    >         }
    >      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    >             var total = 0;
    >             var myroute = result.routes[0];
    >             for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    >                 total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    >             }
    >             total = total / 1000;
    >             return total;
    >         }
    >         function computeTotalDuration(result) {
    >             var total = 0;
    >             var myroute = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
    >             return myroute;
    >         }
    >         function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, wayA, wayB) {
    >             debugger;
    >             directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    >             google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {
    >                 debugger;
    >                 calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay.getDirections(), wayA, wayB);
    >             });
    >             directionsService.route({
    >                 origin: wayA.getPosition(),
    >                 destination: wayB.getPosition(),
    >                 optimizeWaypoints: true,
    >                 travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    >             }, function (response, status) {
    >                 if (status === 'OK') {
    >                     debugger;
    >     
    >                     var route = response.routes[0];
    >                     wayA.setMap(null);
    >                     wayB.setMap(null);
    >                     pinA = new google.maps.Marker({
    >                         position: route.legs[0].start_location,
    >                         map: map,
    >                         icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|00FF00|000000"
    >                     }),
    >                     pinB = new google.maps.Marker({
    >                         position: route.legs[0].end_location,
    >                         map: map,
    >                         icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=E|FF0000|000000"
    >                     });
    >                     google.maps.event.addListener(pinA, 'click', function () {
    >                         infowindow.setContent("<b>Route Start Address = </b>" + route.legs[0].start_address + " <br/>" + route.legs[0].start_location);
    >                         infowindow.open(map, this);
    >                     });
    >                     google.maps.event.addListener(pinB, 'click', function () {
    >                         debugger;
    >                         infowindow.setContent("<b>Route End Address = </b>" + route.legs[0].end_address + " <br/><b>Distance=</b> " +
    > computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections()) + " Km
    > <br/><b>Travel time=</b> " +
    > computeTotalDuration(directionsDisplay.getDirections()) + " <br/> " +
    > route.legs[0].end_location);
    >                         infowindow.open(map, this);
    >                     });
    >                 } else {
    >                     window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    >                 }
    >                 directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    >             });
    >         }
```