# Getting unexpected lines in google map path when drawing path between source and destination and connecting all points(cities)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

> Note:click on View on Google Map button only after entering source and
>   destination and add route points only after entering source and
>   destination and dont left any route points textbox blank(i.e dynamic textbox)

Source code taken from source answered by **geocodezip**:[Inconsistent behaviour drawing a route between two points in Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176212/inconsistent-behaviour-drawing-a-route-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

```js
// Code goes here

 var cnt = 1;
    var autocomplete = [];
    var marker = [];
    var markers = [];
    var usedIds = [];
   var map = null;
    var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;
    var insertTextboxId = [];

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('source'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = places.getPlace();
            var data=
                     {
                         "LocationName": document.getElementById("source").value,
                         "lat": place.geometry.location.lat().toString(),
                         "lng": place.geometry.location.lng().toString()
                     }
            if (markers.length > 0)
            {
                markers.splice(0, 1, data)
            }
            else
                markers.splice(0, 0, data);// splice(position, numberOfItemsToRemove, item)
        });
        var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place1 = places1.getPlace();
            var data =
                     {
                         "LocationName": document.getElementById("destination").value,
                         "lat": place1.geometry.location.lat().toString(),
                         "lng": place1.geometry.location.lng().toString()
                     }
            if (markers.length == 1) {
                markers.splice(1, 1, data);
            }
            else if(markers.length > 0)
              markers.splice(markers.length - 1, 1, data)
        });
    });





function GenerateSourceDestinationPoint() {
  if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class='fieldwrapper' id='field" + cnt + "'/>");
    var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + cnt + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + cnt + "'  />");
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    $("#abc").append(fieldWrapper);
    var newInput = [];
    var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + cnt);
    var txtboxId = 'Txtopt' + cnt;
    newInput.push(newEl);
    setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0, txtboxId);
    cnt = cnt + 1;
  } else
    alert("Cant create more than 5 textbox")
}

function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i, txtboxId) {
        insertTextboxId.push(txtboxId)
        autocomplete.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i]));
         var idx1 = autocomplete.length - 1;
        var idx = markers.length - 1;
        markers[idx + 1] = markers[idx];
        markers[idx] = {};
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[idx1], 'place_changed', function () {
            var pos = idx1 + 1;
            var place = autocomplete[idx1].getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
         }
    var autoTextbox=
        {
          "LocationName": document.getElementById(insertTextboxId[idx1]).value,
                                   "lat":autocomplete[idx1].getPlace().geometry.location.lat().toString(),
 "lng": autocomplete[idx1].getPlace().geometry.location.lng().toString()
        }
            markers[idx] = autoTextbox;
            initialize();
        });
    }

   function initialize() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[0].lat), parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            strokeColor: '#F3443C'
        });
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < markers.length) {
                var src = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
                                                 parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
                var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: src, map: map });
                bounds.extend(smarker.getPosition());
                var des = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i + 1].lat),
                                                 parseFloat(markers[i + 1].lng));
                var dmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: des, map: map });
                bounds.extend(dmarker.getPosition());
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                        poly.setPath(path);
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
  html, body, #map_canvas {
        height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }

    /*
        Provide the following styles for both ID and class,
        where ID represents an actual existing "panel" with
        JS bound to its name, and the class is just non-map
        content that may already have a different ID with
        JS bound to its name.
        */

    #panel, .panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

        #panel select, #panel input, .panel select, .panel input {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        #panel select, .panel select {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #panel i, .panel i {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="initialize()" value="View on Google Map" />

    <br /><br />
    <label>Source</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="source" id="source">
    <br /><br />
    <label>Destination</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="destination" id="destination">
    <br /><br />
    <button onclick="GenerateSourceDestinationPoint()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" >Add Points</button>
    <div style="border: 1px solid -moz-nativehyperlinktext;"></div>
    <div id="abc">
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <div style="height:400px;width:1000px">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

I want to draw path between my source and destination and connecting all my points(i.e cities) falling in between source and destination

For Eg:If my source is **Swansea, United Kingdom** and destination is **London, United Kingdom** with my Route points like this:

**1**)Adding **first route** points that is **Cardiff, United Kingdom**.Getting perfect output like below:
[image]

**2**)Adding **Second route** points that is **Newport, United Kingdom**.Getting perfect output like below:[image]

**3**)Adding **third route** points that is **Bath, United Kingdom**.Getting perfect output like below:[image]

**4**)Now problem comes when i change my **2nd** route point **Newport, United Kingdom** to **Bristol, United Kingdom** then i am getting unexpected lines in google map like below:[image]

**5**)**Expected Output**:[image]

Comment: You have problem with you data. check the point lat,lng or their order

Comment: you can check in console.i am getting all my data in perfect order.in my markers array my all data are coming in appropriate position.you can check in the console of my provided demo

Comment: where is the demo? . you are refer to the code?

Comment: yeah i am referring to the code but you can run it and check output or if you want i can create plunker for you

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip:I have provided a complete tested readable example.you want me to edit some code?

Comment: @geocodezip:This time i have tried my best to provide a minimal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need waypoints, include them in the directions service request.  Your issue is putting the pieces of the route together.

```
function initialize() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[0].lat), parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: '#F3443C'
    });
    var lat_lng = [];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
        map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition()); 
   var src,des;
   var waypoints = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (i===0) {
            src = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
                                             parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
            var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: src, map: map });
            bounds.extend(smarker.getPosition());
        } else if (i==markers.length-1) {
            des = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
                                             parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
            var dmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: des, map: map });
            bounds.extend(dmarker.getPosition());
        } else {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
            waypoints.push({location: latlng,
                            stopover:true});
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                waypoints: waypoints,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
            });
        }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/171vk4ov/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var cnt = 1;
var autocomplete = [];
var marker = [];
var markers = [];
var usedIds = [];
var map = null;
var maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed = 5;
var insertTextboxId = [];

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('source'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = places.getPlace();
    var data = {
      "LocationName": document.getElementById("source").value,
      "lat": place.geometry.location.lat().toString(),
      "lng": place.geometry.location.lng().toString()
    };
    if (markers.length > 0) {
      markers.splice(0, 1, data);
    } else
      markers.splice(0, 0, data); // splice(position, numberOfItemsToRemove, item)
  });
  var places1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'));
  google.maps.event.addListener(places1, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place1 = places1.getPlace();
    var data = {
      "LocationName": document.getElementById("destination").value,
      "lat": place1.geometry.location.lat().toString(),
      "lng": place1.geometry.location.lng().toString()
    }
    if (markers.length == 1) {
      markers.splice(1, 1, data);
    } else if (markers.length > 0)
      markers.splice(markers.length - 1, 1, data)
  });
});





function GenerateSourceDestinationPoint() {
  if (cnt <= maxNumberOfTextboxAllowed) {
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class='fieldwrapper' id='field" + cnt + "'/>");
    var valueStr;
    if (cnt == 1) {
      valueStr = "Cardiff, UK";
    } else if (cnt == 2) {
      valueStr = "Newport, UK";
    } else if (cnt == 3) {
      valueStr = "Bath, UK";
    } else {
      valueStr = "";
    }
    var fName = $("<input type='text' class='fieldname' id='Txtopt" + cnt + "'  name='TxtoptNm" + cnt + "' value='" + valueStr + "' />");
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
    $("#abc").append(fieldWrapper);
    var newInput = [];
    var newEl = document.getElementById('Txtopt' + cnt);
    var txtboxId = 'Txtopt' + cnt;
    newInput.push(newEl);
    setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, newInput, 0, txtboxId);
    cnt = cnt + 1;
  } else
    alert("Cant create more than 5 textbox");
}

function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete, inputs, i, txtboxId) {
  insertTextboxId.push(txtboxId);
  autocomplete.push(new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i]));
  var idx1 = autocomplete.length - 1;
  var idx = markers.length - 1;
  markers[idx + 1] = markers[idx];
  markers[idx] = {};
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[idx1], 'place_changed', function() {
    var pos = idx1 + 1;
    var place = autocomplete[idx1].getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }
    var autoTextbox = {
      "LocationName": document.getElementById(insertTextboxId[idx1]).value,
      "lat": autocomplete[idx1].getPlace().geometry.location.lat().toString(),
      "lng": autocomplete[idx1].getPlace().geometry.location.lng().toString()
    }
    markers[idx] = autoTextbox;
    initialize();
  });
}

function initialize() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[0].lat), parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    strokeColor: '#F3443C'
  });
  var lat_lng = [];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  var src, des;
  var waypoints = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      src = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
        parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
      var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: src,
        map: map
      });
      bounds.extend(smarker.getPosition());
    } else if (i == markers.length - 1) {
      des = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
        parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
      var dmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: des,
        map: map
      });
      bounds.extend(dmarker.getPosition());
    } else {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
      waypoints.push({
        location: latlng,
        stopover: true
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }
  service.route({
    origin: src,
    destination: des,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
      }
      poly.setPath(path);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
/*
        Provide the following styles for both ID and class,
        where ID represents an actual existing "panel" with
        JS bound to its name, and the class is just non-map
        content that may already have a different ID with
        JS bound to its name.
        */

#panel,
.panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#panel select,
#panel input,
.panel select,
.panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}
#panel select,
.panel select {
  width: 100%;
}
#panel i,
.panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="initialize()" value="View on Google Map" />

<br />
<br />
<label>Source</label>
<input type="text" value="Swansea, UK" name="source" id="source">
<br />
<br />
<label>Destination</label>
<input type="text" value="London, UK" name="destination" id="destination">
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="GenerateSourceDestinationPoint()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add Points</button>
<div style="border: 1px solid -moz-nativehyperlinktext;"></div>
<div id="abc">
</div>

<br />
<br />
<div style="height:400px;width:600px">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You always rocks.Thanks a ton.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue: geocoding runs asynchronously. There is no  guarantee that the route-callback will be executed in the desired order.

When you get these straight lines the order will be mixed up(happens also in the original demo), because you always append the overview_polyline to the path.

You must first create the entire path(in the correct order) and then draw the polyline.

However:

1. It's not a good approach to create always a new Map(this will affect you map-loads-quota)
2. when you limit the waypoints to 5, you may use the DirectionsService to request the complete route(up to 8 waypoints are possible)

Comment: Thank you so much for the ans but can you post some code which demonstrate of what you are saying in your ans like how i do create entire path and draw the polyline?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have search alot and didnt get anything regarded of what you are saying