# show route by road between multiple locations on a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a code to show the route between multiple locations on a google map. 
It is a using a polyline. However, for the return route to the destination it shows 'as the crow flies'. 
I am not using a google API key. Do I need to be? How do I use it if I do? Could this be causing the issue? 
I've tried the answer from the link suggested and it doesn't work all the time.

I would have thought this would be a fairly common question - how to plot multiple locations using php. 
I've been working on it for a while now and I can't find a solution. How do I get it to stop showing the return route as the crow flies but only ON THE ROAD?
The code I have is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var map = null;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       var markers = [

        <?php 
                // loop through the rows of data
                if( have_rows('tour_site', $ID) ):

                 $info_places = array();
                  $info_all_places = array();                 
                    while( have_rows('tour_site', $ID) ) : the_row();
                     //display a sub field value
                        $name = get_sub_field('name');
                        $long = get_sub_field('long');
                        $lat = get_sub_field('lat');
                        $info_places = array("name" => $name, "long"=>$long, "lat"=>$lat);
                        $info_all_places = array($info_places);
                        foreach ($info_all_places as $info) {
                        ?>
                        { 
                             "title": <?php echo "'" . $info['name']  . "'"; ?>,
                             "lat": <?php echo "'" . $info['lat'] . "'"; ?>,
                             "lng": <?php echo "'" . $info['long'] . "'"; ?>,
                        }, 
                        <?php 
                        }
                endwhile;
                else :   
                endif;
            ?>


            {
               "title": 'XXX',
               "lat": 'XXX',
               "lng": 'XXX', 
             }
   ];
   </script>

<!-- <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/114281111391296844949/driving-directions.xml&amp;up_fromLocation=xxx&amp;up_myLocations=<?php echo $destination; ?>&amp;up_defaultDirectionsType=&amp;up_autoExpand=&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=55&amp;title=Directions+by+Google+Maps&amp;lang=en&amp;country=US&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script> -->  
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[0].lat),
            parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: '#F3443C'
    });
    var lat_lng = new Array();

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position:map.getCenter(),
                   map:map,
        title:markers[0].title
                 });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(evt) {
        infowindow.setContent(this.get('title'));
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) < markers.length) {
            var src = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat), 
                                             parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
            var smarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:des, 
                                      map:map,
                                      title:markers[i].title
                                     });

google.maps.event.addListener(smarker, "click", function(evt) {  
    infowindow.setContent(this.get('title'));
    infowindow.open(map,this);
});       
            var des = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i+1].lat), 
                                             parseFloat(markers[i+1].lng));
var dmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:des, 
                                      map:map,
                                      title:markers[i+1].title
                                     });
bounds.extend(dmarker.getPosition());
google.maps.event.addListener(dmarker, "click", function(evt) {  
    infowindow.setContent(this.get('title'));
    infowindow.open(map,this);
});            
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                    poly.setPath(path);
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
            });
        }
    }
} 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
   </script>

        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 600px; height: 450px">   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: the suggested link does not solve the issue.

Comment: brilliant answer solves this problem completely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404499/plotting-a-route-on-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Check the returned status parameter google.maps.DirectionsStatus. 
It might give you an indication for the problem.

If you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT you should put a delay between the directions service calls or call it only once with an array that contains up to 10 waypoints.

Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints).